# Checking the input and output file are not the same in Python

Tags: python

I have a python script that takes in two arguments, the name of the input and output files, i.e. it starts of like

```
inputFile=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
outFile=open(sys.argv[2],'w')
```

Then performs whatever operation reading from inputFile and writing to the outFile.

Now a few times through human error I've accidentally given the same argument twice, the result being that my input file is replaced with a blank line. Is there are a straight-forward way to stop this happening?

I thought it might be as simple as adding

```
if sys.argv[1]==sys.argv[2]:
        inputFile.close()
        outFile.close()
```

immediately after the first lines above, but this already leaves the file blank.

Comment: using the same logic try checking if the filepaths of 'inputFile' and 'outputFile' match

Comment: Do the check first, then open the file.

Comment: Thanks I'm so used to opening all files at the start it didn't even occur to me I could check before opening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do :

```
import os
if os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1]) != os.path.realpath(sys.argv[2]):
   inputFile=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
   outFile=open(sys.argv[2],'w')
else:
   raise ValueError('Input and output files are the same')
```

This will prevent human mistakes by raising a welcomed error that won't destroy your input file.

`os.path.realpath` will transform any relative path to an absolute path, so that, even if the strings are different, you can raise the error when absolute paths are identical (thanks @Jean-François Fabre for reminding me this)

Answer (score 1):

opening the file for writing immediately truncates the file, so the damage is already done when you compare the strings.

That said:

- on windows filesystems, the protection is "built-in" since if the file is open as read mode, it cannot be open as write mode at the same time: good (there's a "grey area" for networked filesystems, though)
- on Linux/Unix, the risk is there. But comparing the name isn't enough. What if both different paths point on the same file after all? (consider: `foo/bar` and `/mydrive/foo/bar` or `foo/../bar` and `bar`)

You could use `os.path.realpath()` on both files prior to comparing for instance to resolve relative paths that could be different (that wouldn't solve symbolic link problems, but it's better than nothing)

And for the windows "gray area" I was mentionning, comparing the lowercase version of the names would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The input file is becoming blank because open(filename, 'w') overwrites a file with whatever needs to be placed in it.  'w' is useful for file creation and then writing to that file.  I'd suggest trying open(filename, 'a') for appending a pre-existing file.  I can't quite remember if this creates a file if it's not already existing, but it sounds like you have 2 existing files already, so append should be what you need.

If you decide to go the if sys.argv[1] == sys.argv[2] method, try placing str() around each item you're comparing, just to be certain it's comparing them properly.